# Producing Random Pairs From A String

Tags: python, string, list, random

Given a string such as "HELP", I need to produce the following:

```
["HE",
"HL",
"HP",
"EH",
"EL",
"EP",
"LH",
"LE",
"LP,
...]
```

For all combinations. Any nice BIF's that can do this?
Much Appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce a random list of say 10 entries, the following could be used:

```
my_random_list = [''.join(random.sample('HELP', 2)) for x in range(10)]
print my_random_list
```

This would print something like:

```
['LP', 'PE', 'HL', 'HP', 'LE', 'HP', 'EH', 'LH', 'LE', 'LH']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
s="HELP"
res=list(itertools.permutations(s,2))
```

The two represents the number of letters you want in each element.